# Java HttpSessionListener: how to customize for different types of sessions?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, httpsession

I need to be able to differentiate between session categories; just like this:

```
public final class MyHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    private static final AtomicInteger counterA = 
            new AtomicInteger();

    private static final AtomicInteger counterB =
            new AtomicInteger();

    private static final MyHttpSessionListener INSTANCE = 
            new MyHttpSessionListener();

    public static MyHttpSessionListener getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public MyHttpSessionListener() {}

    public int getNumberOfAClients() {
        return counterA.get();
    }

    public int getNumberOfBClients() {
        return counterB.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        System.out.println("Creating a session...");

        User user = 
                (User) se.getSession()
                         .getAttribute(Config.CURRENT_USER_ATTRIBUTE);

        switch (user.getUserType()) { <--- Here, user is null!
            case A:
                counterA.incrementAndGet();
                break;

            case B:
                counterB.incrementAndGet();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        // Similar to sessionCreated.
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem of nullness in the above switch statement is due to the fact that the listener is called before I have any opportunity of setting the user object to the session via `session.setAttribute(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I found is to add methods to the listener in question that increment the counters. Next, just call those methods in the log in code:

```
public final class MyHttpSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    private static final AtomicInteger counterA = 
            new AtomicInteger();

    private static final AtomicInteger counterB =
            new AtomicInteger();

    public void incA() {
        counterA.incrementAndGet();
    }

    ...
}
```

(My log in servlet)

```
switch (user.getUserType()) {
    case COUNTERA:
        MyHttpSessionListener.incA();
        break;

    case COUNTERB:
        MyHttpSessionListener.incB();
        break;
}
```